# Using Perl LibXML to read textContent that contains html tags

Tags: html, xml, perl, libxml2

If I have the following XML:

> ```
> <File id="MyTestApp/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml">
>     <Identifier id="page_title" isArray="0" isPlural="0">
>         <EngTranslation eng_indx="0" goesWith="-1" index="0">My First App</EngTranslation>
>         <Description index="0">Home page title</Description>
>         <LangTranslation index="0">My First App</LangTranslation>
>     </Identifier>
>     <Identifier id="count" isArray="0" isPlural="0">
>         <EngTranslation eng_indx="0" goesWith="-1" index="0">You have <b>%1$d</b> view(s)</EngTranslation>
>         <Description index="0">Number of page views</Description>
>         <LangTranslation index="0">You have <b>%1$d</b> view(s)</LangTranslation>
>     </Identifier>     
> </File>
> ```

I'm trying to read the 'EngTranslation' text value, and want to return the full value including any HTML tags. For example, I have the following:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $dom = $parser->parse_file("test.xml") or die;

foreach my $file ($dom->findnodes('/File')) {
  print $file->getAttribute("id")."\n";
  foreach my $identifier ($file->findnodes('./Identifier')) {
      print $identifier->getAttribute("id")."\n";
      print encode('UTF-8',$identifier->findnodes('./EngTranslation')->get_node(1)->textContent."\n");
      print encode('UTF-8',$identifier->findnodes('./Description')->get_node(1)->textContent."\n");
      print encode('UTF-8',$identifier->findnodes('./LangTranslation')->get_node(1)->textContent."\n");
  }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
MyTestApp/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
page_title
My First App
Home page title
My First App
count
You have %1$d view(s)
Number of page views
You have %1$d views
```

What I'm hoping to get is:

```
MyTestApp/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
page_title
My First App
Home page title
My First App
count
You have <b>%1$d</b> view(s)
Number of page views
You have <b>%1$d</b> views
```

I'm just using this as an example for a more complicated situation, hopefully it makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather monkey patching solution, but it works:

```
sub XML::LibXML::Node::innerXML{
  my ($self) = shift;
  join '', $self->childNodes();
}

…
say $identifier->findnodes('./Description')->get_node(1)->innerXML;
```

Oh, and if the encoding becomes a problem, use the `toString` method, it's first argument handles encoding. (I did `use open`, but there were no out of range characters in the xml).

If you don't like the monkey patching. you can change the sub to a normal one and supply the argument, like this:

```
sub myInnerXML{
  my ($self) = shift;
  join '', map{$_->toString(1)} $self->childNodes();
}

…
say myInnerXML($identifier->findnodes('./Description')->get_node(1));
```

Comment: Awesome, worked exactly as I had hoped. Since I will be handling encoded strings eventually, I implemented this:

`sub XML::LibXML::Node::innerXML{
  my ($self) = shift;
  join '', map{$_->toString(1)} $self->childNodes();
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your source XML, you either need to encode the tags as entities or wrap that content in a CDATA section.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with embedding HTML in XML is that HTML is not necessarily 'well formed'.  For example the `<br>` tag and the `<img>` tag are not usually followed by matching closing tags and without the closing tags, it would not be valid in an XML document unless you XML-escape the whole string of HTML, e.g.:

```
<EngTranslation eng_indx="0" goesWith="-1" index="0">You have &lt;b&gt;%1$d&lt;/b&gt; view(s)</EngTranslation>
```

Or use a CDATA section:

```
<EngTranslation eng_indx="0" goesWith="-1" index="0"><![CDATA[You have <b>%1$d</b> view(s)]]></EngTranslation>
```

However, if you restrict your HTML to always be well-formed, you can achieve what you want with the `toString()` method.

If you called `toString()` on the `<EngTranslation>` element node, the output would include the `<EngTranslation>...</EngTranslation>` wrapper tags.  So instead, you would need to call `toString()` on each of the child nodes and concatenate the results together:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');

foreach my $file ($dom->findnodes('/File')) {
    print $file->getAttribute("id")."\n";
    foreach my $identifier ($file->findnodes('./Identifier')) {
        print $identifier->getAttribute("id")."\n";
        my $html = join '', map { $_->toString } 
            $identifier->findnodes('./EngTranslation')->get_node(1)->childNodes;
        print $html."\n";
        print $identifier->findnodes('./Description')->get_node(1)->textContent."\n";
        print $identifier->findnodes('./LangTranslation')->get_node(1)->textContent."\n";
    }
}
```

Note I took the liberty of using binmode to set UTF8 encoding on the output filehandle so it was not necessary to call encode for every print.